# Laravel Datatables with translations and Carbon - first row default language problem

Tags: php, laravel, datatables, internationalization, php-carbon

Today I've experienced some strange issue using translations in **Laravel** with **Carbon** and especially with **Datatables** implementation.

I'm using:

1. Laravel 5.6.38
2. yayra/laravel-datatables-oracle 8.8
3. PHP 7.2.9

Let's assume I have a simple table of `Orders`, which has a `created_at` column, nothing fancy...

I retrieve this data via AJAX from OrderController like this:

```
public function data() {

    // Carbon::setLocale(App::getLocale());

    $orders = Order::get(['id','created_at']);

    return DataTables::of($orders)
        ->addColumn('created_at_humans', function (Order $order) {
            return $order->created_at->diffForHumans();
        })
        ->make(true);
}
```

Finally, my **problem** is that I receive the **wrong translation for the first-row on created_at_humans column ONLY** - it is translated to the default language defined in Laravel.

In other words, this first row does not get translated value from `Carbon` `diffForHumans`, and all further rows are translated properly. If I click any sorting, next page, searching, all gets translated except the older first row, so in next further requests, the wrong data still persists...

If I add:

`Carbon::setLocale(App::getLocale());`

In front of the Datables function call as in example code above, everything works as expected.

I would like to have it working across all my Laravel objects in this project, without any workarounds...

I will gladly appreciate any help or thoughts on this problem...

Comment: How are you setting the locale for Carbon?

Comment: @AkenRoberts It seems Carbon locale is getting automatically set up, but unless I invoke it manually, all my first rows get default lang response... So, in fact, I am not specifying Carbon locale and I think it is somehow populated by Laravel...

Comment: Clarification: the incorrect translation is the default app translation. How are you setting the locale you want to be used, that's working for the rest of the rows?

Comment: @AkenRoberts I use mcamara/laravel-localization. I didn't set locale manually so it is done by the package, based on ,route, session or header vars. I retrieve data via AJAX from unlocalized, authenticated path so the language comes from session used by this file. It seems like the first instance of Carbon is created before Laravels locale set up is finished, so the next one works well, but it is just my gues...